# Mobile data not working

Tags: samsung, connection-issues, mobile-data, data-connection

I have a Samsung Galaxy J510-MN (Latin American version) which I have bought from Mexico (Android 6.0.1). Now, I returned to Germany and put a German SIM Card (Fonic/o2). I get network connection, phone and SMS function works. But, I can't get mobile data. I do have the card charged and I already got mobile data settings sent to my phone by phonic, but still it doesn't connects.
How can I solve this? Or might it be a hardware problem, e.g. my phone can't receive the frequency they used in Germany?

Comment: Check the frequency bands you're SIM provider is using from this website. http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html as per the notes, USA double band will not work with Europe double band and vice versa. Let me know whether this has answered your query such that I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the Network connection in settings? If 2G only or 3G only works, then it might be a band problem.